# Read a file in Java from classpath, absolute path, relative path that includes "../.." path

Tags: java

Before marking this a duplicate, please read! I have searched SO and other repositories for this solution.

The below Spring API works if `filepath` is absolute path `file://some/path` or if its a path in the Classpath `/some/class/path`. However, this API fails to handle relative path that includes "../".

```
File f = new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource(filepath).getfile();
```

I have been working around this issue by falling back to the below if the above fails -

```
File f = new File(filepath)
```

Is there a way to avoid this fallback logic and use a file API that works irrespective of file path?

The other solution I came across that suggests using getClass().getResource() also requires fallback API to deal with absolute/relative paths.

Comment: can you give a full example classpath when it fails to handle relative path?

Comment: Are you talking about loading resources from a path that is a *sibling* path to a path that's on the classpath? Resource paths are not "real" paths to locations on disk -- a resource can only be loaded from a path that is underneath an entry on the classpath. If you want to do IO to arbitrary locations on disk you can't use resource-loading APIs. Instead, simply construct a `File` object directly.

Comment: The relative path I am interested in is not in the classpath. It is relative to current directory, but rather than the typical example that accesses files in a subdir from current dir, I am trying to access a file from the parent directory (for example).

The resource API works for absolute paths and the javadocs dont state that they are not meant for relative paths. Anyway if there is no other solution, I'll stick to my current approach. Thanks

Comment: I don't know enough about how Spring does things to be certain, but in normal Java parlance, "resource" means a byte stream that is named relative to a classpath entry. The class loading space is a "virtual filesystem" of sorts, which can be backed by real files on disk, files inside a JAR or WAR archive, or even more esoteric things like JAR files loaded from a remote URL. As such, APIs that deal with resources aren't designed to cope with things outside the class loading "filesystem", and I imagine that's exactly the restriction you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

```
File absolute = new File(filepath).getAbsoluteFile();
```

And use further what works well:

> The below Spring API works if filepath is absolute path
>   file://some/path